# Perform action depending on variable value in Batch Files

Tags: windows, batch-file

As the title suggest, how exactly would you do two different action (like below) depending on the value of a variable in a Batch file.

E.g.

```
IF %NUMBER% = 2 do ECHO Number 2
IF %NUMBER% = 1 do ECHO Number 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two examples

```
IF "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "Bastie" GOTO :TRUE
REM Insert Code for false
  GOTO NEXT
:TRUE
REM Insert Code for true
  echo Willkommen Zuhause
  REM Jetzt wird der if Zweig verlassen
  GOTO NEXT

:NEXT
echo.Have a nice Day!
```

1. Beispiel

   ```
   IF "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "Bastie" (
   echo Willkommen zu Hause!
   ) ELSE (
   echo Du bist auf Computer: %COMPUTERNAME%
   )
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has [encountered this before](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true). Basically, to fit your scenario:

```
if %NUMBER% EQU 1 goto number1
if %NUMBER% EQU 2 goto number2
:number1
echo Number 1
:number2
echo Number 2
```

Comment: Can you define a range with EQ? E.g. 1-10?

Comment: You CAN test for >= and <= values. Combine that with the conditional statements and goto branching, and you can test for a range. For example, if GEQ 1 is true, test if LEQ 10 is true, and you're there.

Comment: You can also nest if-statements: `if %NUMBER% geq 1 if %NUMBER% leq 10 goto :number1to10`

Comment: @bk1e: Much better! Complex conditionals would get ugly quick with my method. Well, uglier.